# How do I show visitor count in my page?

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, visitors, landing-page

I am using Google Analytics for tracking the visitors on my website. I can view all the stat reports from my Google login.

I am wondering if I could place the visitor summary stat in my home page of my website.

Can I show the reports of Google Analytics on my site's home page?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to go the build-it-yourself route, here's the documentation for the [Analytics data export API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html).

Comment: That's probably the better way. You don't need to rely on a 3rd party service and give them access to your GA account.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using WordPress you can use this plugin to display Visitor counts on your website http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analyticator/

> Includes a widget that can be used to display visitor stat information
>   on the front-end

Comment: I tried the Google Analyticator plugin, but for a reason I couldn't find out, the widget didn't display stats correctly. All pages on the site displayed "3". However, the Post Pageviews plugin worked out of the box: https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-post-pageviews/